# How do I create new Demandware project in eclipse?

Tags: demandware

I'm a newbie. I'd like to study Demandware, but I don't know how to create new Demandware project in eclipse. Is there anyone can instruct me how to create a new Demandware project step by step in eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After installing UX studio in Eclipse IDE, try to follow the below steps:

1. Export the existing site (log in into the Business Manager of your local sandbox and select SiteGenesis in drop-down ,go to “Administration” > “Site Development” > “Site Import & Export")
2. Download the archive than unzip the same
3. Import them in UX studio as "General Project"
4. Create new demandware server and bind all project references
5. Verify the active version under Demandware server properties as well as in your local sandbox, both should be same
6. Go to your sendbox > click on "Storefront"

You have successfully create basic site, now you can customize as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create new project and use Demandware with eclipse. You have to install "UX Studio Plugin" of Eclipse.

Repo Location for eclipse:

Juno - http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio/4.2

Kepler - http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio/4.3

Luna - http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio/4.4

Demandware is not free and neither it is open-source. So, if you have a Demandware Xchange account you will find much detailed instructions on how to use Demandware with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with Demandware project you have to install an Eclipse plugin for Demandware called 'UX Studio'.

For installing this you can goto `Eclipse > help > install new software`. Here you can use [Luna to install the Demandware UX studio plugin](http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio/4.4).

If the plugin installation is successful you can select `Demandware Development Perspective`, which is on right side of the Eclipse toolbar. Now you can create a connection to the sandbox server provided by Demandware.

You will require a `hostname`, your `username` and `password` for connecting to the sandbox server.

After connecting to the server you can upload project cartridges to the server and work on it.